# Return empty content if data is not found in database

Tags: spring-boot

I have a endpoint controller where I want to make a GET request and return data. If data is not found I want to return empty content or nothing. I tried this:

```java
private Service listsService;
    
    
@RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, path = {"id/{id}"})
    public ResponseEntity<Object> find(@PathVariable String id) {
    
        LookupResponse lookupResponse = listsService.findById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(lookupResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    
       .................
    
@Override
public LookupResponse findById(String id) {
    
    Optional<Lists> list = ListsRepository.findById(id);
    
    if(list.isPresent())
    {
        Lists lists = binList.get();
        LookupResponse response = LookupResponse.builder()
               .countryCode(lists.getCountry())
                        .category(lists.getType())
                        .build())
               .build();
    
        return response;
    }
    
    return null;
}
```

What should be the proper way to return `no content status` from endpoint if record is not found into database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the optional API in this way:

```java
@Override
public LookupResponse findById(String id) {
    return ListsRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new SomeRuntimeException("Entity not found"));;
}
```

And then create a ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, using the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {SomeRuntimeException.class})
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNotFound(
            RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        return handleExceptionInternal(
                ex, "Entity not found", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, request);
    }
}
```

*You should probably find a better name for SomeRuntimeException and a better message, or use something generic.*

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to use some generic way to implement this maybe just improving the code into endpoint or Spring service? This looks like a exotic solution?

Comment: @PeterPenzov `ControllerAdvice` is that service and separates the concern into a class that handles REST return when there are exceptions.  Spring Boot will automatically pick it up as a bean and it all works out of the box. You can use `EntityNotFoundException` everywhere and the above class will pick up all the `EntityNotFoundException`s thoughout your API. You could also create and return your own RestResponses, but that requires more boilerplate everywhere.